# How to save a variable to use later in subscription when mergeMap has completed

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am fairly new to rxjs and am having trouble finding the right answer to this problem in the docs and stackOverflow. Any help on how to properly structure this code would be greatly appreciated.

I have a fairly typical Angular app that fetches data from a backend for multiple items that a user has selected. For each selected item, the backend has to look up some data in s3, combine files and send back a tar.gz result as a base64 encoded string.

This result is then saved in the Frontend.

All of this is working well but I would love to be able to sort of 'save' the `id` parameter prior to the API call and use that later in the `subscribe` method when the actual data is written. See code below

Thank you!

I could do with using `concatAll` but I would like to stay with `mergeMap` for performance reasons...

```
// i set up the observable from the items that a user has selected
// each item has an id property

function fetch(): void {

  let itemId;

  from(this.selection.selected)
      .pipe(
        take(this.selection.selected.length),
        tap((item) => itemId = item.id),
        mergeMap((item: ItemType): any => {
          return this.fetchMoreDataForItem(item);
        })
      )
      .subscribe((apiResponse: any) => {
        const blob = this.decodeBlob(apiResponse);

        /* would love to somehow retain the itemId of the fetched
           item here, but of course using 'itemId' from the 'tap'
           call will not work as the mergeMap has already moved
           on to the next API call before the subscription is 
           triggered... */

        this.saveBlobToFile(blob, <WOULD LOVE TO HAVE ITEM ID HERE>);

      },
      (err) => console.error(`Error fetching ${err.stack}`),
      () => {
        console.log('Completed download');
      });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a map operator to create a bundle with apiResponse and your id.

```js
function fetch(): void {

  let itemId;

  from(this.selection.selected)
      .pipe(
        take(this.selection.selected.length),
        tap((item) => itemId = item.id),
        mergeMap((item: ItemType): any => {
          return this.fetchMoreDataForItem(item).pipe(
            map(apiResponse => [apiResponse,item.id])
            );
        })
      )
      .subscribe(([apiResponse,id]) => {
        const blob = this.decodeBlob(apiResponse);
        this.saveBlobToFile(blob, id);

      },
      (err) => console.error(`Error fetching ${err.stack}`),
      () => {
        console.log('Completed download');
      });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way to solve it...

What I am doing now is using `concatAll()` like this:

```js
function fetch(): void {

  const itemIds = [];

  from(this.selection.selected)
      .pipe(
        take(this.selection.selected.length),
        tap((item) => itemIds.push(item.id)),
        map(item => this.fetchMoreDataForItem(item)),
        concatAll()
      )
      .subscribe((apiResponse: any) => {

        const [ id ] = itemIds.splice(0, 1);

        const blob = this.decodeBlob(apiResponse);
        this.saveBlobToFile(blob, id);

      },
      (err) => console.error(`Error fetching ${err.stack}`),
      () => {
        console.log('Completed download');
      });

}
```

But as mentioned: I am new to RXJS as of a few days ago and I am sure there is a more elegant way to handle this so any insights are appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: did you notice that your requests are consecutive(i.e. they are sent one after another has complete) it is much slower than using forkJoin. FYI

Comment: yeah definitely slower using concatAll -- going to try the approaches mentioned below and see what works better...

Answer (score 0):

There is a result selector for `mergeMap` let u pass `item.id` along

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html

```
   mergeMap((item: ItemType): any => {
          return this.fetchMoreDataForItem(item);
        },apiResponse => [apiResponse,item.id])
```